# How to administrate a sinopia server (private npm registry)?

Tags: node.js, npm, sinopia, yapm, iojs

I installed the great [sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) private npm registry.

Its very simple and works like a charm! I love it !

But I can't get what are the administration features..

- is there admin features ?
- can a system admin create a sinopia admin account or the admin features must be run by system admin over ssh ?
- how system admin can create a sinopia admin account ?
- how an admin can control other user registrations, or team membership?
- how an admin can access email  of users (in order to send email notifications for example)

> I also created an issue about that on github: https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/291

Comment: Hi @Remi it seems for adding admin users, you need to add them in config.yaml And I don't think if it provides some information of users/accounts (maybe there is a an endpoint you can get that info, please let me know if you figure it out- I need the same feature too)

Comment: Ok, I will. Could you upvote the question please ? You will increase the probability someone help us on it..

Comment: You can ask it in their github as well

Comment: You're right I will bind this question to an issue on the project.

Comment: Are you one of the contributers for Sinopia Module?

Comment: How can I contribute to this module, did you email the author? I appreciate your help...

Comment: As you said, sinopia is on github: https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia. To contribute to the project, create an issue about a feature you want to develop or a bug to fix, then fork the repository in your own account. Then, clone your fork with git in your PC, work on the code, commit and push frequently, and when you are done,  create a pull request to the upstream project and reference it in the issue you previously created. Sinopia maintainers will see it and can merge it in master branch. The next release will include your improvements.

Comment: Oh that's great; thanks for clarification; I, also, love to integrate it with a DB. Please let me know if you would like to join/cooperate or keep in touch with email or... and add ideas for integrating with a DB,... 

I love to collaborate with others as well.

Comment: In fact I thought about it but didn't do anything yet so, I am interested. Let discuss about it here: https://github.com/rbecheras/sinopia/issues/1